# How to insert integer value using cpp thrift api in cassandra without converting in string

Tags: cassandra, thrift

I am using thrift api for c++ . 
I have column_name as column of integer type . Want to insert value in it.
I am using following code for it--

```
Column c1;     `
c1.__set_name("column_name");
c1.__set_value(size);
c1.__set_timestamp(getTS()); 
client.insert("mykey", columnpath, c1, org::apache::cassandra::ConsistencyLevel::ONE);`
```

does __set_value accepts only string ?  Is there any way to insert integer value without converting in string ?

Comment: Is the Column a Column from cassandra_types.h? If so, it seems like the value can only be std::string. Definition of __set_value: `void __set_value(const std::string& val)`